# how to write complex json format in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I have a Json structure, and I want to create it using Nodejs as a request parameter. I am writing the json format here.

```
{ 
  "accounts": [
    {
        "address": {
        "street_address": "string",
        "locality": "string",
        "region": "string",
        "country": "string",
        "postal_code": "string",
        "phone": "string"
      },
       "admin_user": {
        "email_address": "",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "team",
        "job_title": ""
      },
      "name": "testAccount",
      "plan_id": ",
      "website": "",
      "reseller_id": "",
      "customer_id": "",
      "paid_seats": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Do you want write json to file?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean create it? Do you mean assign it to a variable?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to create a json structure like the above....I have successfully created that last day...:)

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. You have only missed double quotes in "plain_id" value.

Correct:

```
"name": "testAccount",
  "plan_id": "",
  "website": "",
  "reseller_id": "",
  "customer_id": "",
  "paid_seats": ""
```